# is this code secure againt memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, buffer-overflow, fortify

i've run a scan with fortify and says that this line contains possibly a memory leak :

LPTSTR args = _tcsdup(commandArgs.c_str());

i don't see any way how can someone exploit that if commandArgs are user manipulated.

Thank you

Comment: Question Headline is ambiguous

Comment: i've changed it , thank you

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak is going to occur regardless of the commandArgs. `_tcsdup()` allocates new memory, you need to later `free()` the pointer it returns to avoid a memory leak.